# Big time gap in Landsat 5 archive

Tags: landsat-5, earth-explorer

I am trying to download some Landsat 5 images from EarthExplorer, but for the years 1990-2009 I get only 17 results. Does anyone know why is there such an incontinuity? The only filter that I use is the path row.

Comment: Can you provide the link where you are trying to download the data?

Comment: I am trying to download the data from http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/ with filters: the years 1990-2009, path:182, row: 36 and landsat 5 dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look and got 152 results back.

When you specified path and row did you select polygon as opposed to point? Polygon gave me more results.

I put in the path as you specified and the date range 1990-2009.

In the `data sets` menu, I selected `L1-5 MSS`.

you could also include `L4-5 TM C1 Level-1` data set for another 30 results.

For `additional criteria` I specified Landsat 5.

Hope that might help somewhat.

Comment: Unfortunately these results are for multiple path rows and I am interested in a specific area, which can be seen only for the specific path/row (182/36). The only possible explanation that I may think, is that the data is missing due to the privatization of Landsat images until 2001, but that does not explain the missing images from 2001 to 2009.

Comment: Good point. I did specify the path and row too, but just to make sure I had a quick look on the [landsat viewer](http://landsatlook.usgs.gov/viewer.html) - There are only the 17 results you are after there too. Sorry but I think that this is just all there is!

Comment: @ML I am not sure why you are returning so few results. My only guess is that there is a filter set somewhere that is limiting the number of scenes. However, the musing that "missing due to the privatization" is incorrect. Once the landsat archive went public, all scenes were put into the public domain. There is no legacy of "private data".